# How can I iterate and print over multidimensional arrays in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have a 2D array like so

```
$array = [foo,bar,baz], [1,2,3]
```

I need to display these items in a table but cannot figure out how to do it.

```
$array.each do | x, y |
puts x
puts y
end
```

^^ Doesnt work, surely im missing something very simple.

Thanks for your help

Comment: show us what is your expected output result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array = [[:foo,:bar,:baz], [1,2,3]]
array.each do |row| 
  row.each { |entry| puts entry }
end
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to this answer, it has been flagged as low quality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do so :

```
<table>
  <% array.each do |inner_ary| %>
  <tr>
    <% inner_ary.each do |item| %>
      <td><%= item %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to pair the first item in the first array with the first item in the second array, etc.

You could use [`transpose`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) to do that:

```
$array.transpose.each do |x, y|
  puts x
  puts y
end
# foo
# 1
# bar
# 2
# baz
# 3
```